# failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, html, forms

i have this code to

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/datapneu/public/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["pricat"]["name"]);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pricat"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["pricat"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";exit;
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";exit;
            }
        }
```

and all my directory on the server are with 755 permission
and still not working

Comment: Can you please confirm that under your document root (probably `/var/www/html` or whatever) there's a `datapneu` folder containing a `public` folder?

Answer (score -1):

You should try with 777 permission. Also, make sure the directory path actually exists and it is passed correctly (I mean directory separator '\' or '/' depend on servers).

Comment: No, they shouldn't. Giving 777 permission to a directory is generally not a good fix, it's just a cop-out. It's better to set the correct owner for that folder instead.